# If I leave the Overflow queue, can I rejoin it?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So I'm in Lion's Arch Overflow doing a jumping puzzle, and suddenly the popup to leave Overflow and join the main instance of Lion's Arch for my server;

[image]

Since I'm in the middle of doing a jumping puzzle and do not wish to restart or be interrupted again until I finish, I click 'Leave Queue'.

If I leave the queue to join the proper instance of a zone I'm in from the Overflow instance, is it possible to rejoin the queue for the proper instance of the zone without leaving the zone and re-entering it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. Once you hit "Leave Queue", you'll stay in that Overflow until you change zones or log out.

...but why are you worried about switching to an overflow in the middle of a jumping puzzle? Your character remains in the same position both before and after the swap from the overflow. I've switched in the middle of one of the LA jumping puzzles before, and had no issue continuing on once in my "Home" Lion's Arch.

Comment: Oh, I had read somewhere that joining the main instance moved you to a specific point of the map, and that you shouldn't transfer between the two when you're doing things like jumping puzzles...

Comment: @pixel It used to, I believe they fixed that.

Comment: Ah ok, so no longer a problem and I shouldn't worry about switching from overflow at all.